# nuxtjs nuxt-validate not works

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have installed with npm

> npm i --save nuxt-validate

a component for the validation of a form. But not works. Below the plugins/validate.js:

```
import { extend } from "vee-validate";

extend("my-validation", {   message: "This {_field_} is invalid.",   validate: value => {
    // ...
    return true;   } });
```

In my nuxt.config.js:

```
 {src: '~plugins/validate.js', ssr: true}
```

And in my page.vue in the script I have this situation:

import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';

```
export default {
    components: {
        ValidationProvider
    },
```

and in my template this content:

```
              <ValidationProvider rules="my-validation" v-slot="{ errors }" name="nameRegister">
              <input type="text" name="nameRegister" id="nameRegister" tabindex="1" class="form-control"
                     placeholder="Name" value="" v-model="nameRegister">
              </ValidationProvider>
```

During the field writing, nothing happened, why?
thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The ValidationProvider components gives you the `errors` array, but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: I want notify that the field must be populated

Comment: Then I would recommend something along the lines of `<ul v-if="errors.length > 0"><li v-for="error in errors" :key="JSON.stringify(error) v-text="error"></li></ul>`

Comment: Thanks, can explain in detail? Where I Need to put this code?

Comment: After your `<input` within the `<ValidationProvider`. You need to display the errors and determine what to do if the errors exist.

Comment: No change with <ValidationProvider  rules="my-validation" v-slot="{ errors }" name="nameRegister">
                      <input type="text" name="nameRegister" id="nameRegister" tabindex="1" class="form-control"
                             placeholder="Name" value="" v-model="nameRegister">
<div v-if="errors.length > 0">errore</div>
                      </ValidationProvider>

Comment: I suppose you need to check your validation rule